# Symmetrical encryption of data in a shared SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, encryption

I have a C# Windows application that uses an SQL server to store its data. The application uses LINQ to SQL to access the data from the database.

One of the problems I am having is the inability to figure out how to encrypt certain data in the database (for example passwords). There could be many instances of the application running on the network at any one time, and they *all* need access to the encrypted data, so I need a method that will be global.

I've seen solutions such as asymmetric encryption (with the keys wrapped using RSA), but I have no clue how to implement this so that each instance of the application can access the private keys etc.